# Multi-Thread (Append Text To TextBox)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Done my fair share of looking this up but it just doesn't make sense..

I know we have to use delegates to update a textbox thats on the Main UI.

Here is the code in the a nutshell:

Initiate the thread that will capture chats:

```
ChatQuery = New Thread(AddressOf FetchChats)
ChatQuery.Start()
```

FetchChats Code Simplified:

```
SetTextBoxWithInvoke(Form5.TextBox2, MESSAGE)
```

SetTextBoxWithInvokeCode:

```
Private Sub SetTextBoxWithInvoke(ByVal TB As TextBox, ByVal msg As String)
        If TB.InvokeRequired Then
            TB.Invoke(New AddToMessageBoxDelegate(AddressOf SetTextBoxWithInvoke), New Object() {TB, msg})
        Else
            TB.Text &= msg
        End If
    End Sub
```

The Problem?? Invoke is never required,  and the new message is never appended to the textbox I need to be appended to.

Delegate:

```
Public Delegate Sub AddToMessageBoxDelegate(ByVal TB As TextBox, ByVal msg As String)
```

Comment: There's no need to define your own delegates any more. The `Action` and `Func` delegates can be used to invoke `Subs` and `Functions` respectively, with zero to 16 parameters. In your case, an `Action(Of TextBox, String)` is what you'd use.

Comment: hi Jimmy,  even though moving the code from Form1 to its local Form5 now works.  I am interested in your method.  How exactly can I append this text to my TextBox2 using Action?

Comment: You just get rid of your `AddToMessageBoxDelegate` delegate and use `Action(Of TextBox, String)` instead. Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the default instance of the form here:

```vb
SetTextBoxWithInvoke(Form5.TextBox2, MESSAGE)
```

Default instances are thread-specific so, if you execute that code on a background thread, rather than using the existing `Form5` instance that was created and displayed on the UI thread, it will create a new instance on the current thread. There's no need to invoke a delegate to access that instance so `InvokeRequired` is always `False`.

You need to use the actual instance of `Form5` that already exists. How exactly you do that depends on the circumstances. If the code that makes the call is already in that form then just use `Me`, which is implicit if you don't explicitly use another reference anyway. Otherwise, it's up to you to get the required reference into the required object to be used.

If the code is not in a form already then maybe you should not be doing it that way at all. Instead, you can use the `SynchronizationContext` class. You get the current instance when your object is created on the UI thread and you can then call its `Send` or `Post` method to marshal back to the UI thread without an explicit `Control` reference. That might not work in your case though, because you'd still need a reference to the correct `TextBox`.

Comment: I love your answer,  but you lost me.  I get that I am creating a new instance of form5.  what I don't get is how to to tell the code to send the info to the Form5.Textbox2 I want it to get to?

Comment: @StavrosPehlivanidis, where is the code in your second snippet located?

Comment: I actually got it working by moving the code form Form1, to Form5 and calling the Me.Textbox2 method.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Before I go.  Any Idea on how to Append to my textbox with the invoke method?